# How to limit a key binding to a single key

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, plugin-fzf

I'm having trouble putting to words what I'm looking for, please mark as duplicate if appropriate

I have a key binding that launches a search based on a fuzzy finder (specifically bindings to fzf and fzf.vim for searching for files, based on [this blog](https://statico.github.io/vim3.html))

```
nmap ; :Buffers<CR>
nmap <Leader>t :Files<CR>
nmap <Leader>r :Tags<CR>
```

The trouble is, sometimes I press `<Leader>t` ... *some search string*, and the beginning of my search string is apparently a keybinding somewhere which is messing up my search. As a workaround, I press space as if it were part of the keybinding to start up the search, but that is not ideal.

Is it possible to disable all keybindings that start with `<Leader>t` or possibly tell vim to immediately execute the binding (greedily?) instead of waiting for more bindings?

Comment: Assuming your mapleader is backslash. What does `:map \t` print?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I was able to find which plugins are populating my key mappings using `:map \t`, and disabled them accordingly [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515416/vim-disable-insert-mappings-of-plugins)

Comment: Also try using `nnoremap`